# «Великая масса» — статус выражения

Tags: грамотная-речь, словосочетания, типы-ошибок

Сегодня, из интервью: «...обманов очень много, их **великая масса**».
[Разговор шел о том, как "дурят нашего брата" в автосервисах.]

На слух мне это словосочетание не понравилось.
Нашла употребление: [здесь](https://books.google.ee/books?id=cQXpCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT237&lpg=PT237&dq=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=qzWjbPdZyM&sig=ACfU3U3rCOWNyyWh2MJCt7_6eLYP9zVyfw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0sb7D69LiAhUktYsKHSQvDhwQ6AEwDXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0&f=false) (*Область Мазурских озер — область морен; **великая масса** валунов использована немцами на шоссе и каменные стройки*) и [вот здесь](https://books.google.ee/books?id=wf1ODwAAQBAJ&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=9bOxrQqibv&sig=ACfU3U2PAd7r6LyjuEHYeQxdtrN9uRa2qg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0sb7D69LiAhUktYsKHSQvDhwQ6AEwEHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0&f=false) (*Истинная толпа народная, истинная **великая масса** людская, с сотнею душевных оттенков и способностей*).

И все равно почему-то не нравится. (Избыточно, что ли?)
Подскажите, правильно ли так говорить?

Comment: Да, на мой слух тоже кривовато. Наверное, потому что "великая масса обманов" - это что-то неудобоваримое. "Огромная" ещё туда-сюда. Но в устной речи я бы вряд ли заметил. Каких-то формальных критериев правильности-неправильности привести не могу, просто личное мнение.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по возрасту источников, "*великая масса*" - в прошлом **устойчивое** словосочетание, ныне вышедшее из широкого употребления, в отличие от "**великого множества**" чего-либо счётного.

Answer (score 0):

В том же смысле, среди условно исчисляемых масс (тысячная, миллионная), употребимы и неисчислимые: огромная, гигантская. Среди них, в отношении народной, живой людской общности, у *великой* массы — особая стать, полностью соответствующая масштабному понятию «народ».

P.S. с антипримером. Припомнился текст этикетки к щётке, где на известном языке это слово было сведено до пародии на себя самоё: «Метла велика электростатична».